# Корректное масштабирование на Комикслейте

Tags: css

Приветствую обитателей StackOverflow.

Над этой проблемой я периодически ковыряюсь уже несколько лет. Тестовая страница https://comicslate.org/furry/ambers/0001 *Это вики для коллективных переводов веб-комиксов (в том числе программистских ;) с помощью скриптовых наклеек поверх оригинальных изображений*.

Если вы обладатель экрана с большим разрешением, для вас всё выглядит прекрасно, а вот владельцам смартфонов и старых мониторов смотреть на немасштабируемую картинку неудобно. Однако по ВебВизору Яндекса я вижу, что применять браузерное масштабирование читатели ленятся.

**Проблема** в том, что исходный плагин http://dokuwiki.org/plugin:aimg переделанный в седые времена из популярной утилиты FotoNotes, заточен под пиксели, мои попытки перетащить его на проценты были неудачны, а автор плагина на него давно забил. Окей, я в курсе про transform: scale, но он меняет див во все стороны сразу, применение transform: translate для сдвига сбрасывает scale, а игры с директивой !important здесь бесполезны. И ещё проблема, как рассчитывать коэффициент для каждого экрана...

**Вопрос**: можно ли обойтись малой кровью, может, я чего-то о трансформе ещё не знаю? Или придётся начинать ковыряться в плагине всерьёз?

Comment: как обычно , css и ни чего больше + `@media` , ваша cms не так сложна doku-wiki - за разумную плату любой возьмётся за работу

Comment: это чистое, кристаллизованное хобби с нулевым бюджетом, к сожалению

Comment: ну тогда вам css в помощь , учите его и применяйте , не сложно , уроков по css как на youtube валом так и на треккерах

Comment: да и с отдельными вопросами типа почему не работает то или другое всегда можно обратится на ru.SO или Тостер

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В итоге я использовал стилевой `translate: scale` с подгонкой его множителя с помощью JS под ширину экрана, плюс `margin` в половину высоты картинки. Всё просто.